What is the smallest possible amplitude of a wave of the first $n$ odd harmonics?
Let's say you have a wave of the form
$$
\cos(x) + a_1\cos(3x) + a_2\cos(5x) + \cdots + a_n\cos((2n+1)x).
$$
What values of $a_n$ yield the smallest possible amplitude, and what is that amplitude?
This question is motivated by electronic music production: How can I get the loudest possible sub-bass with few harmonics, while taking up the least amount of headroom?
For simplicity, I am constraining the problem to involve odd harmonics only, and I am only considering cosine waves with no phase offset. (Sine waves with no phase offset would be equivalent, but cosine has felt simpler for my analysis.) I believe that the solutions to this constrained problem will actually be the optimal solutions in general, but I cannot prove that.
What I have done so far
I've found solutions for the first four cases. Though, for all but the first two I could not find analytic ways, and I am not confident about the correctness of the last one.
Just the first harmonic
Obviously if we have just the fundamental, the amplitude will just be $1$.
Harmonics $1$ and $3$. ($n = 1$)
With the first and the third harmonic, we can solve the problem analytically. We have
$$
\cos(x) + a\cos(3x).
$$
By differentiating and finding zeroes, we can find that this function is maximal where $\cos(x)=\frac12\sqrt{1 - \frac1{3a}}$, with a maximum value of
$$
\sqrt{1 - \frac1{3a}}\left(\frac13 - a\right).
$$
By differentiating this with respect to $a$ and finding the zero, we find that this maximum is smallest when $a=-1/6$. So the solution with the first and third harmonic is
$$
\cos(x) - \frac16 \cos(3x),
$$
which has a maximum of $\sqrt3 / 2$ at $x = \pi/6$.
Harmonics $1$, $3$, and $5$. ($n = 2$)
If we add the fifth harmonic, things got too complicated for me to be able to solve it analytically. But by using a numerical method and asking Wolfram Alpha for the closed forms, I arrived at
$$
\cos(x)+\left(\frac{5\sqrt{2}}{4}-2\right)\cos\left(3x\right)+\left(\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{4}-1\right)\cos\left(5x\right).
$$
This has a maxium value of $2\sqrt{2}-2$, which is achieved at $x=0$ and $x=\pi/4$. I don't have a proof that this is correct, I'm fairly confident given how nice the numbers are.
Harmonics $1$, $3$, $5$, and $7$. ($n = 3$)
With the 7th harmonic, my crappy numerical method wasn't accurate enough to give me any sense of confidence. But it's possible that the solution is
$$
\cos\left(x\right)+\frac{13-7\sqrt{5}}{10}\cos\left(3x\right)+\frac{1}{10}\cos\left(5x\right)+\frac{-7+3\sqrt{5}}{10}\cos\left(7x\right),
$$
which achieves its maximum of $\frac{5\left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)}{2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}}$ at $x=\pi/10$ and $x=3\pi/10$.
I am much less confident that this one is correct.

I have no idea how to tackle this problem as the number of harmonics increases. It seems clear that, as we keep adding harmonics, the maximums will converge to $\pi/4$ while the waves themselves converge to a square wave. But I am wondering if there are closed forms for all the solutions with any number of odd harmonics.
Here is a graph of the four waves I have found: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gj8p1i5htd

You may be right to consider only odd harmonics, but it seems to me you still have to consider phase.

@DavidK True, that may be an unjustified assumption. I've rephrased the beginning of the question to make it clear that this is a constraint I've imposed to make the problem more manageable, rather than a fact I have proven.

@Polygon I have an idea. You are basically trying to approximate the step function below using a Fourier series. $$ h(x) = \begin{cases} -\alpha, x \in  \left[-\pi,\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \cup  \left(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right] \ \alpha , x\in \left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right] \end{cases} $$ Since the step function is odd, only cosine modes will survive.

Not a complete solution, but a very good approximation for the general solution. Consider the function $h : [-\pi,\pi] \to \mathbb{R}$, periodically extended to $\mathbb{R}$ and defined by  $$h(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{\pi}{4} &, \,\, x\in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \\ -\frac{\pi}{4} &, \,\, x\in \left(-\pi,-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \cup\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right) \\ 0 &, \,\, x=-\pi,-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\end{cases}.$$
Then $h$ can be represented as Fourier series $$ h(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\cos{(2n+1)x} = \cos{x}-\frac{1}{3}\cos{3x}+\frac{1}{5}\cos{5x}-\cdots$$
Summing this directly won't be sufficient as it would lead to Gibbs phenomenon. Instead of the Dirichlet kernel, if we use Cesaro sums, then the partial sums become, $S_1 = \cos{x}$, $S_2 = \cos{x}-\frac{1}{6}\cos{(3x)}$, $S_3 = \cos{x}-\frac{2}{9}\cos{x}+\frac{1}{9}\cos{(5x)}$ and $$S_4 = \cos\left(x\right)-\frac{1}{4}\cos\left(3x\right)+\frac{1}{10}\cos\left(5x\right)-\frac{1}{28}\cos\left(7x\right).$$ These are good approximations to the exact solutions you have presented.The next sum will be $$S_5 = \cos\left(x\right)-\frac{4}{15}\cos\left(3x\right)+\frac{3}{25}\cos\left(5x\right)-\frac{2}{35}\cos\left(7x\right)+\frac{1}{45}\cos\left(9x\right).$$
